# How to make the containers dimension stretch to a childs dimension which is scaled proportionally

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2, positioning

Maybe the title is confusing, so let me explain.

I have a `DIV` container scaled to a certain height with `height: x` and inside the container I have a `IMG` styled with `height: 100%`. Then, the width of the container only stretches to the width of the viewport. The effect I'm trying to achieve is to have the width of the containers match the width of the child element (the image, which is wider than the viewport).

I need this behaviour for a Sencha Touch application where I have a scrolling panel with an image inside it, which needs to stretch to the entire available viewport height (so the container is set to `height: 100%`), but currently, the panel doesn't scroll horizontally because the width of the container only stretches to the width of the viewport, while the image is wider.

**Browser:**

[image: Browser view from jsfiddle.net]

**Code:**

```
div {
    /* make container stretch to width of child */
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}    

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

*Example:* http://jsfiddle.net/hongaar/kBCtP/

**Question:**
What do I need to do to make the container stretch and have to same width as the containing image?

---

**EDIT:**
I've made a new fiddle with the actual problem I'm running into, using Sencha Touch 2: http://jsfiddle.net/hongaar/VPNE7/

Comment: have you tried removing any viewport meta data from the page? and then setting the div containers width and height to exact pixels of the original image?

Comment: I'm using Sencha Touch, so tweaking viewport meta tags is not an option. Setting the height of the container to actual pixels neither, as I want the image to fluidly adapt to different viewport heights.

Comment: what if you set the body width in the html to a size smaller than the elements you're playing with, any luck?

Comment: I'm afraid the solution has to be limited to styling the container and image only, to avoid messing with other components of the Sencha Touch framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/QCHDF/5/

```
Ext.application({
launch: function () {
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout : 'hbox',
        //width: '100%',
        height: Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight(),
        scrollable  : {
            direction       : 'horizontal',
            directionLock   : true
        },
        items : [{
            xtype : 'image',
            mode : 'img',
            src   : 'http://placehold.it/400x100',
            height: Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight(),
            width : 400
        }, {
            xtype : 'image',
            mode : 'img',
            src   : 'http://placehold.it/400x100',
            height: Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight(),
            //width : 400
        }]
    });
}
});
```

Key here is to use `mode : 'img'`

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/kBCtP/9/)

Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

```
.container {
        /* make container stretch to width of child */
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;

        /* for debugging */
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .c1 { top: 0; }
    .c2 { top: 220px; }


    .picture1 {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    .picture2 {
        /* but I can't set absolute height, need to be proportionally */
        height: 200px;
        width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the image to fill the screen vertically (stretch to viewport height), so both container and image must be styled with height set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having the parent set to `display: table;` and not set a width. But this could mess it up in reference to the inline flow of the rest of the doc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't have the desired effect.